# How to add id of created user to user_id column

Tags: php, laravel

There is a code for adding data to the database

```
public function store(Comment $commentModel, User $userModel, Request $request)
{
    $userModel->create($request->all());
    $commentModel->create($request->all());
    return redirect()->route('home');
}
```

Added data to the Comment

```
protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'text', 'created_at', 'updated_at'];
```

Added data to User

```
protected $fillable = ['name', 'created_at', 'updated_at'];
```

How to pass id of added user to Comment in user_id column

Comment: Вам больше повезет, если вы воспользуетесь сайтом https://ru.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not in english

Comment: Get the user ID and add it to an array with `request()->all()` before you create the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function store(Comment $commentModel, User $userModel, Request $request)
{
    $user = $userModel->create(['name' => $request->get('name')]);
    $commentModel->create([
        'user_id' => $user->id,
        'text' => $request->get('text)
    ]);
    return redirect()->route('home');
}
```